# Solr tika remove newline

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am using Solr 5.3.1 with tika to extract pdf for indexing. The process worked but it includes a lot of newline breaks. Is there anyway to remove those newline breaks using analyzer?

Here is my code for the analyzer:

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <!--<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>-->
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\\n])" replacement="" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\u000A" replacement="," />
    <!--<Filter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\\n])" replacement="" replace="all"/>-->
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:-->
    <!--<filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>-->
    <!--<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>-->
  </analyzer>
```

I am tried to example for CharFilter and put the newline break (\n) into stopwords_en.txt. It didn't work. I also tried for the solr.MappingCharFilterFactory. I tried to put either 
`"\n"=> "<br>"` or `"\\n" => "<br>"`. It didn't work also.

Could anyone help for removing the newline breaks?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is your query-time analyzer, which is what run when user submits a query. Your Tika post-processing happens in the **index** time analyzer. So, try defining it there. I think *PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory* should be sufficient for that. Alternatively, you could look into [TrimFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#TrimFilterFactory).